# help speeding up a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Need help speeding up a stored procedure

```
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[yearlynetsales]
    (
        @YearToGet int, 
        @current datetime
    ) 
    AS
        SET @YearToGet = 2006;

        WITH Years AS (
            SELECT DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) [Year]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT [Year]-1 FROM Years WHERE [Year]>@YearToGet 
        ),
    q_00 as (
    select
          DIVISION
         , DYYYY
         , sum(PARTY)         as asofPAX        
        , sum(NetAmount)     as asofSales 
        , sum(OtherAmount)     as otherSales         
    from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
    INNER JOIN Years                     ON B101BookingsDetails.DYYYY = Years.Year
    where SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude) and Booked <= CONVERT(int,DateAdd(year, Years.Year  - Year(getdate()), DateAdd(day, DateDiff(day, 0, getdate()), 1)))
      and DYYYY = Years.Year and SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude) and SDESCR  IS NOT NULL
    group by DIVISION, DYYYY, years.year
    having  DYYYY = years.year
    ),
    q_01 as (
    select     
          DIVISION 
        , DYYYY 
        , sum(PARTY)         as YEPAX 
        , sum(NetAmount)     as YESales
     , sum(OtherAmount)     as YEotherSales
    from  dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
    INNER JOIN Years                     ON B101BookingsDetails.DYYYY = Years.Year
    where SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude) 
    group by DIVISION,  DYYYY , years.year
    having  DYYYY = years.year
    ),
    q_02 as (
    select
          DIVISION
        , DYYYY
        , sum(PARTY)         as CurrentPAX        
        , sum(NetAmount)     as CurrentSales  
        , sum(OtherAmount)     as CurrentotherSales           
        from dbo.B101BookingsDetails 
    INNER JOIN Years                     ON B101BookingsDetails.DYYYY = Years.Year
    where SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude) and  Booked <= CONVERT(int,@current)
      and DYYYY = (year( getdate() )) and SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude) 
    group by DIVISION,  DYYYY 

    )

    select
          a.DIVISION 
         , a.DYYYY
        , asofPAX        
        , (asofSales + othersales) as asofSales      
       , YEPAX 
        , (YESales + YEothersales) as YESales
          , CurrentPAX 
        , (CurrentSales + Currentothersales) as CurrentSales  
      ,(asofSales + othersales)/ ISNULL(NULLIF((YESales + YEothersales),0),1) as percentsales,
               CAST((asofpax) AS DECIMAL(5,1))/yepax as percentpax 




    from q_00 as a
    join q_01 as b on (b.DIVISION = a.DIVISION  and b.DYYYY = a.DYYYY) 
    join q_02 as c on (b.DIVISION = c.DIVISION)
    JOIN Years as d on (b.dyyyy = d.year)
    where A.DYYYY <> (year( getdate() )) 
    order by a.DIVISION,  a.DYYYY ;
```

Comment: Whats the analyzer say?  What indexes are in place?

Comment: What is the structure of your tables?? How many rows of data are there in each table involved??

Comment: well in the analyzer it takes 45 seconds to load

Comment: and the query is getting all its information from a single table. but the problme is it is running the query over and over again for the years i believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, lots of places to tweak this; let's start with changing the NOTs to LEFT JOIN's with NULLs:

```
     q_01 AS ( SELECT    DIVISION
          , DYYYY
          , SUM(PARTY) AS YEPAX
          , SUM(NetAmount) AS YESales
          , SUM(OtherAmount) AS YEotherSales
  FROM      dbo.B101BookingsDetails
            INNER JOIN Years ON B101BookingsDetails.DYYYY = Years.Year
            LEFT JOIN dbo.regionexlude r ON SDESCR = r.columnname
  WHERE     r.columnname IS NULL
     /*where SDESCR not in (select * from dbo.regionexlude)*/
  GROUP BY  DIVISION
          , DYYYY
          , years.year
  HAVING    DYYYY = years.year  ),
```

Comment: thanks my numbers are now a little different but if you have anymore tweaks it would be great

Comment: What does the HAVING clause gain you?  I think you can pull it out, and reduce some programming cycles.

Comment: its still at 40 seconds anything else, sorry i just need to get it under 20

Comment: Where are your indexes on the main table?  Also, does your YEARS table NOT include the current year?  q_02 could also remove the join to the year table since you're using a WHERE clause to statically focus on a value (prob won't buy you much...)

Comment: my years are generated at the top do you think i should just make a table that had the years already that way it doesnt have to do that

Comment: and no the current year should not be included in the year.years

Comment: but i couldnt get it into my sp to stop it from being included if you could help it would be great

Comment: Hey sorry; I got pulled into a meeting. if all you're using the Years to sdo is generate list of years, why not simply use a BETWEEN statement (e.g, WHERE DYYYY BETWEEN @YearToGet and YEAR(GETDATE())?

Answer (score 1):

Add Set Statistics Profile On before your query. You can then see which parts are taking the longest to execute

SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON

SELECT * FROM [TABLE]

[Show Performance Data in SQL server](http://wraithnath.blogspot.com/2011/01/getting-performance-data-from-sql.html)

Comment: When you run the query it should appear in the lower panel. I have added a screenshot on my blog